# Peer List when discovered through wifi p2p displays image and user name

Tags: android, networking, wifip2p

When peer list is discovered using wifi p2p's onPeersAvailable() method, it displays the device name and address, can we display an image in addition to the name and address?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener.html), you don't get such information through the peer discovery.

So if you need additional information delivered through the discovery method, you would then need to distribute them through the service discovery. Though for images there is no default ways on doing it, but indeed you could define your own custom logic for doing so.